# sqlite c interface persistent error qt

Tags: database, qt, sqlite, runtime-error

I want to perform a simple query (drop table) with `sqlite` native interface and I persistently run into `SQLITE_ERROR` as I try to prepare the statement. I tried everything as I was afraid of string compatibility (qt strings can be a pain sometimes) but every it always gives me the same the code is the following:

```
    sqlite3_stmt *query;
    std::string tmp = "DROP TABLE ?";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, tmp.c_str(), tmp.size(), &query, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)return     FALSE;
    if(sqlite3_bind_text16(query, 1, str.utf16(), -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK) return FALSE;
    if(sqlite3_step(query) != SQLITE_OK) {
      std::cerr << sqlite3_errmsg(db);
      return FALSE;
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(query);
```

I hope sincerely someone out there can help.

Comment: it was as Anton pointed out thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass table names as parameters (it applies to most database APIs supporting parameters, maybe even *all* database APIs).

Comment: thanks a lot :) i did't new that i guess that i'll prepare the query trough string appending since i need the name to be variable